# How to use every image from a specific folder using ejs in node.js?

Tags: node.js, image, foreach, ejs

I want to take every image from a specific folder and use it on a page.
The images have random names but only jpg format for now which may change in the future.

Can I do that with ejs or do I have to use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using latest JavaScript syntax (probably need `babel`).  Also make sure you install `koa@2` not the old `koa`.

```
import {readFile} from 'fs-promise';
import listFilepaths from 'list-filepaths';
import Koa from 'koa';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.request.querystring.indexOf('.jpg')>0) {
    const fname = ctx.request.querystring.split('=')[1];
    ctx.body = await readFile(`images/${fname}`);
  } else {
    let images = await listFilepaths('./images',{relative:true});
    images = images.map(i=>i.replace('images/',''));
    ctx.body = `${images.map(i=>`<img src="/?i=${i}"/>`)}`;
  }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: so u are basically saying that i cant do that with ejs at all?

Comment: Dont need EJS if using current JavaScript.

Comment: is that possible with express also?